# Is it possible to set an alarm so it will only ring once?

Tags: iphone, notifications, alarm, clock

I like to have an alarm go off hourly to help me stay focused, and I’ve set my phone up to play church bell sounds for each hour. This works well, except that the alarms will keep playing forever (or for a long time in any case) unless I stop it. I don’t want to have to do anything, especially pick up my phone. I just want it to play once and stop on its own. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using alarms, which as you have found need to be silenced, set up a repeating Reminder instead. Reminders only play their 'chime' once. By using the iOS Reminders App you will also have the benefit of having it sync to your macOS device, if you have one. Of course, the macOS Reminders App can also be used in the same way.

The smallest period you can use is an hour. If you need smaller time periods, use more than one reminder and vary it's start time, e.g hourly starting at 0900, hourly at 0915, hourly at 0930, hourly at 0945. This would give you a chime every 15 minutes. You can also set custom repeat times, e.g frequency hourly, every 2 hours. That would make the above example 0900, 0915, 0930, 0945, 1100, 1115 etc.. With some clever use you can make it quite complex!

The 'chime' you get will be set by the sound you choose for Reminder Alerts in `Settings | Sounds & Haptics | Reminder Alerts`.

When you no longer wish to receive notifications, delete the reminder. If you mark the reminder as done, it will come back to haunt you in an hour's time, so it must be deleted. Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a way of unscheduling a Reminder while keeping your timing settings intact for future use. If you switch off the time settings for a Reminder, while other information you've added remains, it loses the time settings and you have to setup again.

Other than that, there are many apps available in the App Store (as covered by similar questions on the subject in the past, always pays to check if the question has been asked before...).